# Inline Edit Textarea Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery i'm performing Inline Edit and delete operations for textarea comment.Currently i'm able to Edit/update and delete data everything works fine but one small change in my requirement When i click on edit button i should get the value of label in textarea which i'm not able to achieve at the moment please someone help me out in achieving it Thanks!

[image]

[image: When i click on edit button i should get the value in textarea]

**JQUERY**

```
 $('#demoajax').on('click','.ajaxedit',function()
    {
        var edittrid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        if(pre_tr_id)
        {
            return false;
        }
        pre_tr_id = true;
        var tds = $('#'+edittrid).children('td');
        var tdstr = '';
        var td = '';
        pre_tds = tds;

        for(var j=0;j<field_arr.length;j++)
        {
            tdstr += "<td><textarea type='"+field_arr[j]+"' name='"+field_name[j]+"' value='"+$(tds[j]).html()+"' placeholder='"+field_pre_text[j]+"'></textarea></td>";
        }
        tdstr+="<td>"+updatebutton +" " + cancel+"</td>";
        $('#createinput').remove();
        $('#'+edittrid).html(tdstr);
    });
```

Comment: `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`

Comment: Sorry Tushar i'm newbie to JQuery can you help me out where exactly i need to place your code?

i have textarea tag in for loop can it be done in it?
THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put value attribute with textarea. You will have to give textarea value as below :

```
tdstr += "<td><textarea type='"+field_arr[j]+"' name='"+field_name[j]+"' placeholder='"+field_pre_text[j]+"'>"+$(tds[j]).html()+"</textarea></td>";
```